# cakephp 3 plugin localization

Tags: cakephp, localization, internationalization, cakephp-3.0

i wrote a plugin `(AdminView)` as a theme and i want to localize it.
i generate `pot` file using

```
bin\cake i18n extract --plugin AdminView
```

the `pot` file created by bake at

`root/plugins/AdminView/src/Locale/default.pot`

i moved it to

`root/plugins/AdminView/src/Locale/fa_IR/default.po`

and i set the locale to `fa_IR`
but cakephp dose not load it . 
but when i move files to the

`root/src/Locale/fa_IR/default.po`

it loads perfectly.
the question is how can i load `po` files in the plugins directory ?

i cleared the  `root/tmp/cache/persistent` every time i test

Comment: Plugins cannot provide messages for the `default` domain unless their paths are included in your apps `App.paths.locales` config, or a custom loader is being defined. _Where exactly_ are you trying to translate _what exactly_, and _why exactly_?

Comment: Ok . 
let me explain from the beginning. my project is divided to 2 parts .

first is `admin` prefix and second is the main site . i used two plugins one for admins theme and one for main site theme  and i want to translate the part needed translation in each plugin separately. 

the reason is that i need multi lang admin panel and site .
the view files are in the plugins src under the Template folder

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, plugins cannot provide messages for the `default` domain unless their paths are included in your apps `App.paths.locales` config, or a custom loader is being defined for the `default` domain.

By default, plugins provide translations for their respective plugin domain, ie for `AdminView` that would be `admin_view` (`admin_view.po` or `.mo` accordingly), and you'd use it like `__d('admin_view', 'message')`.

If all your translation function calls are inside of the plugins, then you should probably stick to the convention, and use the respective plugin domains, which you can always override at application level, or provide fallbacks for in your app level `default.po`.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Internationalization & Localization > Language Files](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#language-files)**
- **[Cookbook > Internationalization & Localization > Using Translation Functions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#using-translation-functions)**